# Tic Tac Toe program that includes reports

Tags: python, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe, simulation

I'm working to use everything I'm learning in my reading and former code reviews to keep making this program better. I'm getting stuck on the following issue: the `play_many_games` and `game_is_over` methods in the `GamesEngine` class both call reports. I don't like this because the method names don't at all lead one to believe that reports are being called. I'd rather have functions do only one thing: so... basically I can't figure out the right way to call reports which need to be called after games end. Note that the main function in the top level module (`tic_tac_toe.py`) is doing the "one thing" of initializing reports and starting the games (i.e. *there*, in the main function, I feel justified touching "game" and "report" even though they are two different things). But once the games are started I find it harder to justify calling reports within the `GamesEngine` class which should just be about games.

Here is what I'm wondering: do I just suck more and more out of the `GamesEngine` class and dump it into the main function so that main knows when games are ending and can therefore handle the actual report calls? Or is there some design pattern I can use that watches for games to end and then calls reports (if yes, I don't know how to do it just yet)?

Basically I'm confused about how the `GamesEngine` class can somehow communicate with the `reports.py` module in a clean way that follows good clean programming principles.

Here are the three modules and their contents:

**tic_tac_toe.py**

```
"""Submit jobs for the requested number of games. Request game-reports.

Usage:

    python3 tic_tac_toe.py <number of games>
"""
import sys
from game import GamesEngine
from reports import (GameReport, ManyGamesReport)


def main(number_of_games):
    """Request report instructions. Request game initiation.

    Args:
        number_of_games: Number of games to play
    """

    report_requests = prepare_reports(number_of_games)

    games_engine = GamesEngine(*report_requests)

    play_games(games_engine, number_of_games)


def prepare_reports(number_of_games):
    """Create a report request based on the number of games. If 100 games or less requested, order printout for every game.
    Statistics on wins/ties for all games are always ordered.

    Args:
        number_of_games: Number of games to play
    """
    report_requests = []
    if number_of_games <= 100:
        report_on_game = GameReport()
        report_requests.append(report_on_game)
    report_on_many_games = ManyGamesReport()
    report_requests.append(report_on_many_games)
    return report_requests


def play_games(games_engine, number_of_games):
    """Initiate the games.

    Args:
        games_engine: An instance of GamesEngine that drives all games and knows when reports should be called.
        number_of_games: Number of games to play
    """
    games_engine.play_many_games(number_of_games)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

**game.py**

```
import random


class GamesEngine:

    def __init__(self, *reports_requested):
        self.game_result_as_string = ''  # For unit tests this needs to remain an instance variable
        self.state_of_game = GameState()
        self.find_game_outcome = GameOutcome()
        self.row_index_for_move = None
        self.column_index_for_move = None
        self.reports_requested = reports_requested

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(*{})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.reports_requested)

    def play_many_games(self, num_games_to_play):
        """Request report instructions. Request game initiation.

        Args:
            num_games_to_play: Number of games to play
        """
        while num_games_to_play > 0:
            self.play_one_game()
            num_games_to_play -= 1
        report_on_many_games = list(self.reports_requested).pop()
        report_on_many_games.report_outcome_statistics()

    def play_one_game(self):
        self.state_of_game = GameState()
        game_over = False
        while not game_over:
            self.make_move()
            self.update_who_moves_next()
            game_over = self.game_is_over()

    def make_move(self):
        # randomly select an available square for next move
        square_for_next_move_as_list_of_list = random.sample(self.state_of_game.available_squares, 1)
        self.row_index_for_move = square_for_next_move_as_list_of_list[0][0]
        self.column_index_for_move = square_for_next_move_as_list_of_list[0][1]
        # remove, from the available_squares list, the square we will use
        self.state_of_game.available_squares.remove([self.row_index_for_move, self.column_index_for_move])
        # make move
        self.state_of_game.board[self.row_index_for_move][self.column_index_for_move] = self.state_of_game.next_move

    def update_who_moves_next(self):
        temp = self.state_of_game.next_move
        self.state_of_game.next_move = self.state_of_game.previous_move
        self.state_of_game.previous_move = temp

    def game_is_over(self):
        self.game_result_as_string = ''
        if self.row_index_for_move is not None:
            self.game_result_as_string = self.find_game_outcome.find_winner_or_tie(self.state_of_game, self.row_index_for_move, self.column_index_for_move)
        if self.game_result_as_string:
            for report_calls in self.reports_requested:
                report_calls(self.state_of_game, self.game_result_as_string)
            return True
        else:
            return False


class GameOutcome:

    def __init__(self):
        self._letter_dict = {'X': -1, 'O': 1, ' ': 0}
        self._game_state = None
        self._row = None
        self._col = None
        self._game_outcome = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def find_winner_or_tie(self, game_state, row, col):

        self._set_board_and_move(game_state, row, col)

        if self._check_row() or self._check_column() or self._check_main_diagonal() or self._check_off_diagonal() or self._check_tie():
        return self._game_outcome

        return ''

    def _set_board_and_move(self, state_of_game, row_index_of_move, column_index_of_move):
        self._game_state = state_of_game
        self._row = row_index_of_move
        self._col = column_index_of_move

    def _check_row(self):
        """Checks the row containing the most recent move to see if there is a win"""
        total = sum([self._letter_dict[self._game_state.board[self._row][column]] for column in range(3)])
        if abs(total) == 3:
            winning_letter = self._game_state.board[self._row][self._col]
            self._game_outcome = winning_letter
            return True
        return False

    def _check_column(self):
        """Checks the column containing the most recent move to see if there is a win"""
        total = sum([self._letter_dict[self._game_state.board[row][self._col]] for row in range(3)])
        if abs(total) == 3:
            winning_letter = self._game_state.board[self._row][self._col]
            self._game_outcome = winning_letter
            return True
        return False

    def _check_main_diagonal(self):
        """If most recent move is on the main diagonal, checks the main diagonal to see if there is a win"""
        if self._row == self._col:
            total = sum([self._letter_dict[self._game_state.board[diagonal_indexing][diagonal_indexing]] for diagonal_indexing in range(3)])
            if abs(total) == 3:
                winning_letter = self._game_state.board[self._row][self._col]
                self._game_outcome = winning_letter
                return True
        return False

    def _check_off_diagonal(self):
        """If most recent move is on the off diagonal, checks the off diagonal to see if there is a win"""
        if self._row + self._col == 2:
            total = sum([self._letter_dict[self._game_state.board[off_diagonal_indexing][2 - off_diagonal_indexing]] for off_diagonal_indexing in range(3)])
            if abs(total) == 3:
                winning_letter = self._game_state.board[self._row][self._col]
                self._game_outcome = winning_letter
                return True
        return False

    def _check_tie(self):
        if len(self._game_state.available_squares) == 0:
            self._game_outcome = 'Tie'
            return True
        return False


class GameState:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = None
        self.available_squares = None
        self.initialize_board_and_available_squares()
        self.next_move = 'X'
        self.previous_move = 'O'

    def initialize_board_and_available_squares(self):
        self.board = [[' ' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
        self.available_squares = [[i, j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]

    # Printing an instance of the class will display a standard
    # tic tac toe game board.
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n" + self.board[0][0] + "|" + self.board[0][1] + "|" + self.board[0][2] + "\n" + self.board[1][0] + "|" + self.board[1][1] + "|" + self.board[1][2] + "\n" + self.board[2][0] + "|" + self.board[2][1] + "|" + self.board[2][2]
```

**reports.py**

```
class ManyGamesReport:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count_wins_and_ties = {'X': 0, 'O': 0, 'Tie': 0}

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def __call__(self, board, win_result):
        self.count_wins_and_ties[win_result] += 1

    def report_outcome_statistics(self):
        total_games = sum(self.count_wins_and_ties.values())
        print('Proportion of X wins: ' + str(self.count_wins_and_ties['X'] / total_games))
        print('Proportion of O wins: ' + str(self.count_wins_and_ties['O'] / total_games))
        print('Proportion of ties: ' + str(self.count_wins_and_ties['Tie'] / total_games))


class GameReport:

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    # call turn_on_end_of_game_reporting from main.py to run_random_tic_tac_toe_simulation this report method
    def __call__(self, board, win_result='Tie'):
        print(board)
        if win_result != 'Tie':
            print(win_result + ' won\n')
        else:
            print(win_result + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) pretty well. Just two minor things: the [maximum line length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) should be 79 for characters, and 72 for docstrings. In *game.py*, for example, you have a line of 241 characters! Another thing is [imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

   > Imports should be grouped in the following order:
   >
   > 1. Standard library imports.
   > 2. Related third party imports.
   > 3. Local application/library specific imports.
   >
   > You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

   So, instead of this:

   > ```
   > import sys
   > from game import GamesEngine
   > from reports import (GameReport, ManyGamesReport)
   > ```

   you should have:

   ```
   import sys

   from game import GamesEngine
   from reports import GameReport, ManyGamesReport
   ```

   Note that I removed redundant parenthesis.
2. In *tic_tac_toe.py* you have a hardcoded value `100` that defines the maximum number of games that will be printed. While it is clear what it does from the docstring, I advise you to make it an input parameter of the `prepare_reports` function.
3. In the same function you create and fill the `report_requests` list with one-two objects: `ManyGamesReport()` and/or `GameReport()`. And I see a problem here. The thing is that lists in Python are used only for homogeneous data. If you have heterogeneous data in a list then it means you are doing something wrong - you should rethink your design, think of other data structure, or simply use tuples, depending on the case. In fact, all this structure with reports seems too complicated for such a simple programming task. If I were you I would completely redesign the program.
4. When creating a board:

   > ```
   > self.board = [[' ' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
   > ```

   you don't need `i` and `j`. For throwaway variables you should use [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) `_`:

   ```
   self.board = [[' ' for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
   ```
5. Why are `GameOutcome` and `GameState` separate classes? For me this didn't make any sense... Also, in `GameEngine` you have:

   > ```
   > self.game_result_as_string = self.find_game_outcome.find_winner_or_tie(self.state_of_game, self.row_index_for_move, self.column_index_for_move)
   > ```

   This just doesn't seem right. All this separation of logic to different classes is very confusing for me.
6. Function `play_games` is redundant. It just calls a `play_many_games` method of the `games_engine` object. You should take that call outside into `main` function.
7. `play_many_games` has the following lines:

   > ```
   > while num_games_to_play > 0:
   >     self.play_one_game()
   >     num_games_to_play -= 1
   > ```

   This is not Pythonic. Use `for _ in range(num_games_to_play)` instead.
8. In `GamesEngine` you create empty `GameState` but then you rewrite it by empty
   `GameState` in `play_one_game`. This seems useless. Consider rewriting that part.
9. `square_for_next_move_as_list_of_list` is a very long name for a variable! Usually, we don't write a type or structure details of a variable in its name. So, at least, remove the `as_list_of_list` part.
10. In `make_move` you generate a move and then delete it from a list of available moves. But how about using `random.sample(self.state_of_game.available_squares, 9)`
    and just iterate over obtained random values? The code should look cleaner, and the performance shouldn't be a problem in this case.
11. The following function:

    > ```
    > def update_who_moves_next(self):
    >     temp = self.state_of_game.next_move
    >     self.state_of_game.next_move = self.state_of_game.previous_move
    >     self.state_of_game.previous_move = temp
    > ```

    can be rewritten as `a, b = b, a`. This is a standard Python solution for swapping variables values.

---

Just for fun I fun I wrote the same program but using functional approach. Feel free to compare. The square field here can have a variable size. You can also specify a number of players and a number of consequent cells to win.

```
import collections
import itertools
import random
from typing import (Counter,
                    Iterator,
                    List,
                    Tuple)


FieldType = List[List[str]]


def run_games(count: int,
              *,
              printable_games_count: int = 5,
              players: Tuple[str, ...] = ('X', 'O'),
              cells_in_line: int = 3,
              cells_to_win: int = 3) -> None:
    """Plays and prints results of Tic-Tac-Toe games"""
    wins_counter = collections.Counter()
    for _ in range(count):
        field, winner = game_result(size=cells_in_line,
                                    players=players,
                                    cells_to_win=cells_to_win)
        wins_counter[winner] += 1
        if count <= printable_games_count:
            print_game_result(field, winner)
    print_final_stats(players, wins_counter, count)


def game_result(*,
                size: int,
                players: Tuple[str, ...],
                cells_to_win: int) -> Tuple[FieldType, str]:
    """
    Plays a Tic-Tac-Toe game of specified size
    and returns final field with a winner
    """
    field = [[' ' for _ in range(size)]
             for _ in range(size)]
    symbols = itertools.cycle(players)
    possible_indices = list(itertools.product(range(size), repeat=2))
    indices = random.sample(possible_indices, size ** 2)
    for (row, col), symbol in zip(indices, symbols):
        field[row][col] = symbol
        for line in corresponding_lines(field, row=row, col=col):
            if win_condition(line, symbol=symbol, cells_to_win=cells_to_win):
                return field, symbol
    return field, 'Tie'


def corresponding_lines(field: FieldType,
                        *,
                        row: int,
                        col: int) -> Iterator[List[str]]:
    """
    Yields row, column and diagonals (if applicable)
    for the input indices
    """
    yield field[row]
    yield [field[index][col] for index in range(len(field))]
    if row == col:
        yield [field[index][index] for index in range(len(field))]
    if row + col + 1 == len(field):
        yield [field[index][-index - 1] for index in range(len(field))]


def win_condition(line: List[str],
                  *,
                  symbol: str,
                  cells_to_win: int) -> bool:
    """Checks if a line has enough same symbols for a victory"""
    return sum(element == symbol for element in line) == cells_to_win


def print_game_result(field: FieldType, winner: str) -> None:
    """Prints field and a winner"""
    print(*prettify(field), sep='\n')
    winner_string = f'{winner} won' if winner != 'Tie' else 'Tie'
    print(winner_string, end='\n' * 2)


def prettify(field: FieldType) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Yields rows of the field for pretty printing"""
    yield from map('|'.join, field)


def print_final_stats(players: Tuple[str, ...],
                      counter: Counter,
                      count: int) -> None:
    """Prints proportions of victories for each player"""
    for player in players:
        print(f'Proportion of {player} wins: {counter[player] / count}')
    print(f'Proportion of ties: {counter["Tie"] / count}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_games(3,
              printable_games_count=4,
              players=('a', 'b', 'c'),
              cells_in_line=5,
              cells_to_win=5)
```

Output:

```
c|c|c|c|c
b|b|b|a|b
b|b|b|c|c
b|a|a| |a
a|a|a|a|c
c won

a|b|c|b|c
a|b|c|c|a
b|a|b|c|a
b|c|b|b|a
a|a|a|c|c
Tie

b|a| |a| 
b|a|c|b| 
c|a|c| |c
 |a|a|c|b
c|a| |b|b
a won

Proportion of a wins: 0.3333333333333333
Proportion of b wins: 0.0
Proportion of c wins: 0.3333333333333333
Proportion of ties: 0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't add an improved version of the code as an edit. It would be better to ask a new question. Please, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a `Game` class, which the user would call like so:

```
Game(number_of_games=10)
```

The `Game` instance would then keep track of the games by itself.

`Game` would then call `GameEngine` which would handle **only one game** and would  be run like so:

```
# somewhere in `Game`
result = GameEngine().run()
self.report(result)
```

I think all the report stuff should go in the `Game` class itself as methods. If I am not clear enough, maybe I should draw you a picture...

```
├── Game
│   │ with attributes to keep track of the score
│   ├── __init__(number_of_games)
│   ├── nextgame()
│   └── report(result)
│
└── GameEngine
    │ with attributes to keep track of the board
    ├── __init__()
    └── ... the game engine ...
```

`Game` would be kind of the "meta" version of `GameEngine` if you think of it like that. The user won't be exposed to the internals of the game but only to the "launcher".

What is the separation of concerns. Well `Game` doesn't care about the board.

And `GameEngine` doesn't care about the user, and the score.

You can test the `GameEngine` easily because it only includes the core stuff.

You can test `Game` easily by using `Mocking`. How can I do "mocking" ? Simple add this before doing `unittesting`:

```
class GameEngine:
    def run(): return 'Tie'
```

See [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) for more info.